# At the time of chaincode instansiate getting error Error: could not send: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

Using Linux 16.04 and docker All the containers are running fine .Successfully installed the chaincode on core peer.
But At the time of chaincode instansiate

```
peer chaincode instantiate -o orderer.example.com:7050 -C $CHANNEL_NAME -n fabcar -l "golang" -v 1.0 -c '{"Args":[""]}' -P "OR ('Org1MSP.member','Org2MSP.member')"
```

Geeting error

```
`Error: could not send: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport is closing`
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: at very first time get this error Error: Error getting broadcast client: rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = transport: write tcp 172.18.0.7:37626->172.18.0.2:7050: write: broken pipe

Comment: after that error converted as described in question.

Comment: 172.18.0.7:37626 is cli container and 172.18.0.2:7050 is orderer

Comment: are you using fabcar example

Comment: add the steps you followed and log for orderer.example.com.

Comment: Creating my custom orderer not default one .

Comment: does this issue resolved?

Comment: @Maxi this issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 6):

I was facing this issue because I enabled tls on the peer but not providing the tls and ca file to the orderer at the time of chaincode instantiate.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

1. Bring down the network
2. Disable TLS in below files by commenting environment variables listed below.

   ```
   base/docker-compose-base.yaml
   base/peer-base.yaml
   docker-compose-cli.yaml:    
   docker-compose-e2e-template.yam
   ```

   ENV:

   ```
   CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED
   CORE_PEER_TLS_CERT_FILE
   CORE_PEER_TLS_KEY_FILE
   CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE
   ```
3. Bring up the network

Another way is to pass TLS certificate as an argument to peer fetch channel command.